# Compare multiple lines in a graph using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I create a dataframe with this code:

```
sg = df[['Month','price','Year']].groupby(['Year','Month']).mean().reset_index().sort_values(['Year','Month'])
sg
```

And I want to compare the months of two years with line plots. I attempted to do this as follows:

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))


chart=sns.lineplot(x=sg['Month'], y=sg['price'], ax=ax)
sns.despine(left=True)
```

and I get the this visualization:

[image: first_picture]

But I want to create an image like this:

[image: second_picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `hue` or a `style` [parameter](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html).

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))


chart=sns.lineplot(x='Month', y='price', hue='Year', data=sg)
sns.despine(left=True)
```

If you do not want the background color which is `ci` parameter add `ci=None`.

Also, notice how I added `data=sg` and I removed `sg[...]` before `x` and `y`. `ax=ax` is not needed as well.

Comment: thanks much. i noticed and practiced. your answer is very open.

Comment: Happy to help, seaborn documentation is quite nice, you will often find answers there just by searching the plot you are drawing and what possibilities it has.

Comment: yeah it has quite good docs. i realized with your link. thanks again. which  Python libraries do you recommend for visualization  . i am learning now :  seaborn and matploblib. I want to be an expert  on data visualization. Currently i have business intelligence job for 2 years.

Comment: Most often you will end up using a platform for that like tableau or something like it. You can check bokeh library.